# How to reset the vscode UI between tests?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there is a way to reset the vscode user interface between tests, or at least before/after a full test run? Specifically to clear dialogs.

**Background**

I have a project created using the yeoman code generator recommended in the [vscode extension development tutorials](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/yocode).

When I run the tests by launching "Extension Tests" from the Debug tab, a dedicated vscode window appears to host the running tests.

One of the tests triggers showing of a modal warning dialog, created by calling:

```
vscode.window.showWarningMessage(message, { modal: true })
```

However, these dialogs seem to persist between test-runs, unless I manually click to close them before the test window closes.

Worse, the dialog instances seem to aggregate - if I don't manually close a dialog at the end of one run, the same instance reappears the next time in addition to the new one added by the new run of the tests.

For the large majority of my tests I am stubbing UI interactions to avoid this issue. But I'd like solve this problem so I can have at least a few focused tests that drive the UI.

I have looked through the [extension reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/overview) and some existing extensions but haven't spotted the solution yet.